# XCUITest application shortcuts

Tags: swift, xctest, xcode-ui-testing, 3dtouch

Is there any way of testing the UIApplication shortcuts within XCUITests?

I know that in order to test 3d shortcuts in a simulator you need a trackpad with force touch, but I was wondering if I could write tests that test my shortcuts.

Comment: Were you able to find a solution for this? I am trying the suggestion from Chase Holland but it doesn't seam to work. I managed to present the app shortcuts menu but only once in a while, it doesn't seam to work reliably, but even when it is presented I can't tap on any of the shortcuts (not even with a mouse directly in the Simulator). Thanks for the update!

Comment: @MiroslavKovac sadly no

Answer (score 0):

Looks like yes! You'll need to expose a private API, though. Exported `XCUIElement` header from [Facebook's WebDriverAgent here](https://github.com/facebook/WebDriverAgent/blob/master/PrivateHeaders/XCTest/XCUIElement.h).

Or, if that's the only thing you need, just expose it ala:

```
@interface XCUIElement (Private)
    - (void)forcePress;
@end
```

And then to force press your icon by going to the springboard and getting your icon element [see my answer here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36168101/840262).

```
class Springboard {
    // this is another private method you'll need to expose (see linked other answer)
    static let springboard = XCUIApplication(privateWithPath: nil, bundleID: "com.apple.springboard")


    /// Open the 3d touch menu
    class func open3dTouchMenu() {
        XCUIApplication().terminate() // this may or may not be necessary depending on your desired function / app state

        // Resolve the query for the springboard rather than launching it
        springboard.resolve()

        // Force delete the app from the springboard
        let icon = springboard.icons["MyAppName"]
        if icon.exists {
            icon.forcePress()
            // do something with the menu that comes up
        }
    }
 }
```

* I have not tested this yet.

Comment: There is no forcePress method for XCUIElement.

Comment: You need to expose the method since it's private. I haven't looked at this since Xcode 9.3, though -- it's possible they have removed it completely from Xcode 10.x.