# .isHittable is sometimes false dependent on which machine im using

Tags: ios, xcode-ui-testing, ui-testing, uitest

I have an app that uses iCloud sync, therefore I need to sign in to iCloud before running UI tests. I've found a way to do that and it works very well - at least on my own computer.

When running the UI test at Nevercode (hosted CI), it fails with:

```
Unable to find hit point for Icon 0x608000362c40: traits: 8594129408, {{-97.
0, 136.0}, {64.0, 82.7}}, identifier: 'Settings', label: 'Settings'
```

https://stackoverflow.com/a/43094450/406055

Dumping the view hirachy I can see that it finds the Settings (icon/app) but it's .isHittable is false, for some reason. So I tried to forceTap() the Settings icon, this just makes the build fail with: "app not started..."
http://samwize.com/2016/02/28/everything-about-xcode-ui-testing-snapshot/
(.isHittable is true on my machine)

Are there any way to take screenshots or in some other way find out what is going on, on the screen during UItest?

In iOS9 it's possible to take screenshots, hvor du I get to then in Nevercode's test report?