# UITest Failed to terminate com.test.abc:3708 after 60.0s; state is still `Running Foreground

Tags: ios, swift, xcode-ui-testing

I have UITests for my app and all the tests are running fine, but sometimes after executing a couple of tests, the other tests start failing due to **Failed to terminate com.test.abc:3708 after 60.0s; state is still `Running Foreground` (4)CreateUserUITest**

Comment: Thanks for sharing your results. We experience the same.

Answer (score 2):

It looks like it's Xcode bug which was not solved still.

http://www.openradar.appspot.com/25548393

I tried to use `@try { } @catch { }` but test was interrupted still if `terminate()` was failed. So I see only one way to fix = delete app if it is not terminated on `setUp()` point: https://stackoverflow.com/a/48715864/751932

Answer (score 1):

Its caused by latest iOS 11.4. More info here:
https://forums.developer.apple.com/thread/94054

Answer (score 1):

As part of our investigation, it was cause by Rosetta emulator, even with latest Xcode.