# How do I erase an Xcode 10 simulator clone through CLI?

Tags: ios, xcode, simulator, ui-testing, parallel-testing

Do they share the same UDID?
How are they implemented under the hood?

The scenario is I have 4 clones running UI tests in parallel. I need a clean simulator for some tests (but want to keep random test order)

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Command to erase all testing simulators (you'll need to restart Xcode after that):

```
xcrun simctl --set testing delete all
```

Overall, it should be better to just reset those sims (you won't need to restart after that):

```
xcrun simctl --set testing shutdown all
xcrun simctl --set testing erase all
```

To erase specific one you first need to get his ID with `list devices` and then shutdown and erase:

```
xcrun simctl --set testing list devices
xcrun simctl --set testing shutdown 2BC2B50E-C4BA-45B9-9C73-AF5097BA1F0B
xcrun simctl --set testing erase 2BC2B50E-C4BA-45B9-9C73-AF5097BA1F0B
```

Thanks Scott McCoy for his answer.

Comment: But how do I reset a specific one? Tests are still running on others, and I need to reset one to prepare it for the "clean slate" test

Answer (score 2):

I have not been able to find any interface with cloned simulators via `simctl`. You can completely remove them by deleting their folder under `~/Library/Developer/XCTestDevices`. They each get their own UUID, but again, they don't get listed in `simctl` as far as I can tell.

Answer (score 2):

You can list clones like this:
`xcrun simctl --set testing list`

But any time I try to use device IDs with xcrun commands they fail with `Invalid device: <device id>`

Answer (score 0):

On your status bar with Xcode open on your mac go to Windows->Devices and Simulators. There you will see a list of all the available simulators and you can add new or delete existing from there.

Comment: Hi, thanks for your answer. I am not seeking to remove a simulator but to erase its data - similar to what `Erase all content and settings does` but through terminal

Answer (score 0):

you can reset all the simulators by:
*xcrun simctl erase all*

to reset a particular simulator use:
*xcrun simctl erase your_simulator_id*

Comment: So as per question, I'm looking to erase a particular clone. How do I find the *clones* simulator id?

Comment: _xcrun instruments -s_ will give you the ids of all simulators